# '\n' cannot be identified when i was running ssh command with parallel command

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-parallel

- Commonly, I can run this command `ssh -lroot [host ip] "echo -e 'test1\ntest2'" > ~/test.txt` to write two lines in test.txt file in host [host ip].
- However, when i used it with parallel, that is `parallel -a argfile -j3 -k --tag ssh -lroot {} "echo -e 'test1\ntest2' \> ~/test.txt"`, it'll ignore '\n' and write 'test1ntest2' actually into test.txt.
- How to make '\n' work as expect in parallel command? Anybody can help to clarify?
- I have tried to add backslash before single quotes as below：
  `parallel -a argfile -j3 -k --tag ssh -lroot {} "echo -e \'test1\ntest2\' \> ~/test.txt"`
  It's still not as expect.
- Tried to add backslash before '\n', also did not work.
  `parallel -a argfile -j3 -k --tag ssh -lroot {} "echo -e 'test1\\ntest2' \> ~/test.txt"`

I just want to write two lines to a certain file of remote server in bulk by using parallel...

Comment: Do you get the same effect, if you use `printf 'test1\ntest2\n'` instead?

Comment: @user1934428 Yes, I do. Also print one line: `test1ntest2n`

Comment: Just to ensure that we are not hunting ghosts: What happens if you change your command into `parallel .... {} "(echo test1; echo test2) >~/test.txt"`? Another test would be `printf 'test1\\\ntest2\\\n'`. The latter assumes that _parallel_ somehow processes the backslash, so a triple-backslash should leave one for the _printf_.

Comment: Another possibility worth trying: You said that you can manually execute the ssh command fine, and the weird behaviour shows only if you stuff it into `parallel`. In this case write a shell script containing the _ssh_  command and test it. If it works, have `parallel` just invoke your shell script, instead of trying all the fancy escapes on the `parallel` command line.

Answer (score 1):

Already fixed this issue with command:`parallel -a argfile -j3 -k --tag ssh -lroot {} "echo -e 'test1\\\\ntest2' \> ~/test.txt"`

I think the parsing process maybe as below:

- normal input:`\\\\n`
- local host shell parses one layer backslash: `\\n`
- parallel command identifys single quotes, keep origin: `\\n`
- ssh parses one layer backslash: `\n`
- 'echo -e' command parses `\n` to new line.

If we change single quotes to double quotes or remove single quotes directly, the number of backslash needs to change to double: `parallel -a argfile -j3 -k --tag ssh -lroot {} "echo -e "test1\\\\\\\\ntest2" \> ~/test.txt"`.
Have fun guys:).

Answer (score 0):

Also try `--nonall`:

```
parallel --slf argfile -j3 -k --nonall --tag --ssh 'ssh -lroot' echo -e 'test1\\ntest2' \> ~/test.txt
```